# SQL Server: Invalid Column Name when using Alias Name

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

Hi Every one I have this query code to retrieve data from DB when I Excute 
I Have Invalid Column Name Expr2,Expr3,Expr4

```
SELECT Isnull(EMP_NUM, 0)           AS Expr1,
       Isnull(Full_name, 0)         AS Expr2,
       Isnull(Mother_Name, 0)       AS Expr3,
       Isnull(Date_of_Birth, 0)     AS Expr4,
       Isnull(Province_of_birth, 0) AS Expr5,
       Isnull(Job, 0)               AS Expr6
FROM   [EMPLOY Main Table]
WHERE  ( Expr2 LIKE N'%' + @Full_name + N'%' )
        OR ( @Full_name IS NULL )
        OR ( Expr3 LIKE N'%' + @Mother_Name + N'%' )
        OR ( @Mother_Name IS NULL )
        OR ( Expr4 LIKE N'%' + @Date_of_Birth + N'%' )
        OR ( @Date_of_Birth IS NULL )
```

Comment: you can not use alias in the where clause. please use the column names. Only order by can you alias

Comment: @Hiten004 Can u show me how to do that

Comment: @Prdp What you suggest to do ??

Comment: Add sample data and expected result based on input parameter.

Comment: When I try it with out Alias name it's work and give me zero for null record but I need use of the ISNULL("column_Name",0)

Comment: @Prdp what you mean please be more specific thanks

Comment: @FarooqAlsaegh - Add sample data and expected result.

Comment: I did that and the result is I get that error above

Answer (score 0):

**here is the code that will with variable list on the bottom script**

```
 SELECT ISNULL(EMP_NUM, '0') AS Expr1
  , ISNULL(Full_name, '0') AS Expr2
  , ISNULL(Mother_Name, '0') AS Expr3
  , ISNULL(Date_of_Birth, '0') AS  Expr4
  , ISNULL(Province_of_birth, '0') AS Expr5
  , ISNULL(Job, '0') AS Expr6 
  FROM            [EMPLOY Main Table] 
  WHERE  
        (Full_name LIKE N'%' + @Full_name + N'%') 
        OR 
        (@Full_name IS NULL) 
        OR
        (Mother_Name LIKE N'%' + @Mother_Name + N'%') 
        OR
        (@Mother_Name IS NULL) 
        OR
        (Date_of_Birth LIKE N'%' + @Date_of_Birth + N'%') 
        OR
        (@Date_of_Birth IS NULL)
```

Comment: That code return all the data from DB

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to change your where clause like

```
SELECT ISNULL(EMP_NUM, 0) AS Expr1
    ,ISNULL(Full_name, 0) AS Expr2
    ,ISNULL(Mother_Name, 0) AS Expr3
    ,Date_of_Birth AS Expr4
    ,ISNULL(Province_of_birth, 0) AS Expr5
    ,ISNULL(Job, 0) AS Expr6
FROM [EMPLOY Main Table]
WHERE (Full_name LIKE N'%' + @Full_name + N'%' OR @Full_name IS NULL) and
 (Mother_Name LIKE N'%' + @Mother_Name + N'%' OR  @Mother_Name IS NULL) and
   (Date_of_Birth = @Date_of_Birth OR  @Date_of_Birth IS NULL)
```

Comment: I try it now...